# Render PDF file in chrome browser using mozilla-pdf

Tags: javascript, cakephp, mozilla, pdf-reader

I am try to render pdf file in browser. So I used `mozilla-pdf.js`, its working fine in firefox but when I try to render PDF file in chrome its just display black page.

So please help to render this PDF file in chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use below :

**http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_php.jsp**

its been tested and worked like charm.

Feel Free to ask.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use something like [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) or [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) to generate the PDF serverside and then let Chrome use its own PDF viewer?

Here's the code to open and show a pdf in your browser via PHP

```
$file='./files/the.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="the.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
@readfile($file);
```

Comment: if he gonna use TCPDF then is it possible to read PDF file using TCPDF.?

Comment: he is rendering so that mean he needs to read it first...without read how can he render it.

Comment: i want to read PDF file in browser as i said i can read in firefox but when i try to read in chrome its just display blank black page.

Comment: Read the content or render the content? Please clarify.